# I am confused about the grammar of the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

> Bloomington is a small city of about 70,000 with cultural resources and opportunities that rival cities many times its size.

https://www.law.indiana.edu/admission/bloomington/bloomington.shtml

I think I can get the meaning of the sentence, but is it grammatical?

Comment: Which part of it makes you feel like it might not be grammatical?

Comment: Without you saying why you think it might be ungrammatical, this is pretty much the same as a proofreading request.

Answer (score 1):

If we are being very strict, we would say the sentence commits an error; it should say:

> ... with cultural resources and opportunities that rival **those of**
>   cities many times its size.

But so many native speakers make this particular "error" when making a comparison that we should understand the sentence to mean that the resources and opportunities are being  compared with other resources and opportunities, not with a city.

Another way to repair the sentence would be like this:

> Bloomington is a small city of about 70,000 yet with abundant cultural resources and opportunities, so that it rivals cities many times its size.

or like this:

> Although it is a small city of about 70,000, Bloomington has abundant cultural resources and opportunities, and rivals cities many times its size.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly grammatical.

It is saying that although Bloomington is a small city, it offers cultural resources (libraries, museums, art galleries, centres of learning) and (business) opportunities that are typical of much larger cities.

Comment: Thanks. But "...that are typical of..."  is found nowhere in the original sentence, could you give some further explanation about this sentence?

Comment: @waytang That's my explanation. The text says the city *rivals* much bigger cities. That's to say, it compares with them in what it offers.